# Not getting the Same ListView item before and After insert using Cursor

Tags: android, android-listview, android-sqlite, android-cursoradapter

I have a `ListView` which by using `CursorAdapter` I m inflating its rows . And I am using `SwapCursor`  in order to refresh the `ListView`.

I am also able to get the `listView` standStill once I add the Content in the DB and Swap the Cursor after that.

Now the Problem is on `swapCursor` / `notifyDatasetChanged` / `changeCursor` it is refreshing the `listView`.But not maitaining the same item which was present Earlier into the listView.

It is changing the content of item by its previous one once I refresh the listView.

This is How I got ListView standStill after `swapCursor()` :

```
if (result_cursor != null) {

            CursorDemo cursorDemo = new CursorDemo(ORMLiteActivity.this , result_cursor);

            cursorDemo.swapCursor(result_cursor);

            View v = listViewDb.getChildAt(0);

            int top = (v == null) ? 0 : v.getTop();

            int firstPosition = listViewDb.getFirstVisiblePosition();

            listViewDb.setAdapter(cursorDemo);

            listViewDb.setSelectionFromTop(firstPosition , top);
            }
```

So Now I would get the same `ListView` item before or After `swapCursor`

[image: Before Insert]

[image: After Second]

Any Answer is Truely Appreciated...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figure using this:

```
    if (result_cursor != null) {

                CursorDemo cursorDemo = new CursorDemo(ORMLiteActivity.this , result_cursor);

                cursorDemo.swapCursor(result_cursor);

                View v = listViewDb.getChildAt(0);

                int top = (v == null) ? 0 : v.getTop();

                int firstPosition = listViewDb.getFirstVisiblePosition();

                int after_insert_position = (firstPosition == 0) ? 0 : firstPosition+1;

                listViewDb.setAdapter(cursorDemo);

                listViewDb.setSelectionFromTop( after_insert_position , top);
}
```